# Python Can't access dictionary

Tags: python, json

Getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when trying to access a dictionary in python. I've tried using `json.loads(r2)` thos produces `"TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"`

Not even sure if Im on the right track here, all I need to do is get the JSON which appears to be in one long string into something like `x['SomeKey']` and the value at those keys using `iteritems()` or similar?

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r2 = r.json()
seq = json.dumps(r2)
print(seq['remotecontrol_id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

`r.json()` already returns a dictionary so I'm not sure why you pass `r2` to `json.dumps` that returns a string (hence the `s`). The error message you received even suggests that ("TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not **dict**")

Your code should be

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r2 = r.json()
print(r2['remotecontrol_id'])
```

Comment: hello all, Ok II modified it like so r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)   
    r2 = r.json()    
    for value in r2:
        print(r2['remotecontrol_id']) 
This produces KeyError: 'remotecontrol_id' its as if the JSON is one long string that can't be broken up??

Comment: @RobD All it means is that the JSON you get does not have `remotecontrol_id` key at the top level. `print` it and see what it looks like...

Comment: DeepSpace Your are correct remotecontrol_id is under another key, Id there anyway to shift down? a level?? The data I need to get at is under this top level key Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that method `dumps` converts a python's `dictionary` into a `string`, therefore in the line `seq['remote...']` you are accessing a `string`. You should access the variable `r2` instead of `seq`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it figured out, sort of...

for i in r2:

print(r2['stuff'][0]['someval1']) 
print(r2['stuff'][1]['asomeval2'])

Anyway, hits works

Thanks for all the great advice!